# Could not spawn process for group /var/www/rubycas

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger, rubycas-server

```
[ 2014-02-10 13:51:00.0173 22995/7f012fa3b700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:883 ]: Could not spawn process for group /var/www/rubycas#default: An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time.
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::throwPreloaderSpawnException(const string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::BackgroundIOCapturerPtr&, const DebugDirPtr&)' (SmartSpawner.h:146)
     in 'std::string Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:566)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:206)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:752)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:804)

[ 2014-02-10 13:51:00.0253 22995/7f0127fff700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2088 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session.
```

This is the error i encountered when i'm trying to access rubycas over apache

Rails 2.3.8

Phusion Passenger version 4.0.37

Ruby 1.8

Thanks,
Swaroop

Answer (score 2):

Try taking a look at this troubleshooting page: [Debugging startup problems](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems)